# Typescript and @octokit/webhooks.js: Constraining event types based on `EmitterWebhookEventName`

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm using the `@octokit/webhooks.js` package which has advanced generic type constraints.

A typical usage is

```
webhooks.on('issue_comment.created', handlers.onIssueCommentCreated);
```

where the function signature is defined as

```
on: <E extends EmitterWebhookEventName>(event: E | E[], callback: HandlerFunction<E, TTransformed>) => void;
```

I'm trying to create a helper wrapper function around the `on` function like the following, which currently does not work:

```
function addWebhook<
  E extends (EmitterWebhookEvent<EmitterWebhookEventName> & {
    payload: { sender: User };
  })['name'] &
    `${string}.${string}`
>(webhooks: Webhooks, event: E | E[], callback: HandlerFunction<E, unknown>) {
  webhooks.on(event, (options) => {
    options.payload.sender; // <-- error: TS2339: Property 'sender' does not exist on type 'EventPayloadMap[Extract ]'.
  });
}
```

I want to constrain this function to only allow `E` which is constrained to `EmitterWebhookEventName`, and such that `EmitterWebhookEvent<E>['payload']['sender']` is of type `User`. Speciically, I'm having difficulty implementing the 'such that' logic.

The main [library types](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks.js/blob/master/src/types.ts) are these:

```
export declare type EmitterWebhookEventName = typeof emitterEventNames[number];
export declare type EmitterWebhookEvent<TEmitterEvent extends EmitterWebhookEventName = EmitterWebhookEventName> = TEmitterEvent extends `${infer TWebhookEvent}.${infer TAction}` ? BaseWebhookEvent<Extract<TWebhookEvent, WebhookEventName>> & {
    payload: {
        action: TAction;
    };
} : BaseWebhookEvent<Extract<TEmitterEvent, WebhookEventName>>;
interface BaseWebhookEvent<TName extends WebhookEventName> {
    id: string;
    name: TName;
    payload: WebhookEventMap[TName];
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you use this wrapper function? Could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a maintainer of the `@octokit/webhooks` lib, and I can help you answer some of your issues.

Right off the bat, the type of the generic `E` is incompatible. It should be a `string` conforming to the type of `EmitterWebhookEventNames`, and not an `object`.

As for the type issue for the `sender` property in the payload, the error you are getting is because the `sender` property isn't always present on the webhook payloads, since the `E` generic doesn't have a value assigned to it, it defaults to every event name.

If you define and use the function this way, you will be able to get the proper payload types in the callback for the specified event(s).

```
import { EmitterWebhookEvent, Webhooks } from "@octokit/webhooks";
import type { EmitterWebhookEventName, HandlerFunction } from "@octokit/webhooks/dist-types/types"
import type { User } from "@octokit/webhooks-types"

const webhooks = new Webhooks({secret: 'foo'});

function addWebhook<E extends EmitterWebhookEventName>(webhooks: Webhooks, event: E | E[], callback: HandlerFunction<E, unknown>) {
  webhooks.on(event, callback);
}

addWebhook(webhooks, "issue_comment.created", (options) => {
  options.payload.sender; // type is User
})
```

Comment: I have the `addWebhook` function because I want to do some specific stuff involving the payload sender before the specific webhook handler executes. So, as such, I want it to only be able to be called by webhook events that have the sender property, so that I can use it generically for all applicable events.

Comment: I think I understand a little better now. You want to make a new type that excludes event names for which the corresponding payload doesn't have the `sender` property

Comment: Something along the lines of this should work: ```import type { EmitterWebhookEvent, EmitterWebhookEventName } from "@octokit/webhooks/dist-types/types";
import type { User } from "@octokit/webhooks-types";
type DropEventsWithNoSender<T extends EmitterWebhookEventName> = EmitterWebhookEvent<T>['payload']['sender'] extends User ? never : T;```